# How to fix bug in Unity tutorial "Identifying the Local Player" OnStartLocalPlayer()?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a bug in this Unity tutorial:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/identifying-local-player?playlist=29690

"The final script will look like this:"

```
    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        GetComponent().material.color = Color.blue;
    }
```

The error is:

```
"Assets/PlayerController.cs(22,9): error CS0305: Using the generic method `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent<T>()' requires `1' type argument(s)"
```

What is the correct function call w/ generic method?

Comment: While it's true that this is a typo in Unity's tutorial, I don't really think it needed to be its own Q&A on here, as the people who can fix it are unlikely to see it.

Comment: It's not meant for "the people who can fix it".
It's meant for people like me...Unity noobs .

Comment: Sure, but if you can't read an error message as explicit as the one given and realize what the problem is, you should be working on your fundamentals before jumping into a game engine.

Comment: I would say you should report it on their bug board, they will fix it and then it wouldn't need to be listed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjJFJrWkoYE

```
public override void OnStartLocalPlayer(){
    //GetComponent().material.color = Color.blue;
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
}
```

Comment: I would use `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color` as MeshRenderer inherits from Renderer, and there is no guarantee that your objects renderer is of type MeshRenderer.  May even be better to store the component you get back and check it isn't null before attempting to modify it to.